# How to turn off the blue dot left behind after using the extent interaction

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I am using the Openlayers extent interaction to allow the user to select an AOI.  After the user does this and removes the drawn extent I would like the blue dot to also disappear.  Currently it just hangs out on the map and then pops back to the mouse once the interactions key is pressed again.

This behavior can be seen in the Openlayers Extent Interaction example [here](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/extent-interaction.html).  Shift+drag starts the extent interaction.  Shift+click removes the extent but the blue dot is left there.  Is there a way to remove this ??   Once the extent is removed there is no other interaction possible with the blue dot, so what is the purpose of it even being there ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out the [API docs](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.Extent.html) for `ol.interaction.Extent`

You can pass a style to `pointerStyle` to update the style of the dot.

```
var extent = new ol.interaction.Extent({
  condition: ol.events.condition.platformModifierKeyOnly,
  pointerStyle: [] // <-- Makes the dot invisible
});
```

```js
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  url: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson',
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: vectorSource
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});

var extent = new ol.interaction.Extent({
  condition: ol.events.condition.platformModifierKeyOnly,
  pointerStyle: []
});
map.addInteraction(extent);
extent.setActive(false);

//Enable interaction by holding shift
this.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 16) {
    extent.setActive(true);
  }
});
this.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 16) {
    extent.setActive(false);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/build/ol.js"></script>

<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Comment: This works well.  The pointer is still there, though, right ??  All this does is hide it ??

Comment: Exactly, you could always remove the interaction if at that point you wanted to stop drawing.